# How to include a new-line in a doctest variable?

Tags: python, newline, doctest

I would like to break text that inputs to a doctest into new lines. Here is a minimal example:

```py
import doctest

def example1():
    """
    >>> txt = '\\n'.join(['abcd', 'efg'])
    """

    return '\\n'.join(['abcd', 'efg'])


def example2():
    """
    >>> txt = '\\n'.join(['abcd',
    'efg'])
    """

    return '\\n'.join(['abcd',
    'efg'])

doctest.testmod()
```

The result is:

```
File "example.py", line 16, in __main__.example2
Failed example:
    txt = '\n'.join(['abcd',
Exception raised:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/doctest.py", line 1329, in __run
        compileflags, 1), test.globs)
      File "<doctest __main__.example2[0]>", line 1
        txt = '\n'.join(['abcd',
                               ^
    SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

The syntax for new lines inside an array works in the body of the function but not in the doc-test. How can I arrange long strings in doc-tests into new lines?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Doc-tests require an explicit newline escaping. So add a backslash:

```
"""
>>> txt = '\\n'.join(['abcd', \
'efg'])
"""
```